# replace numbers inside the brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data inside a column like

```
## col1 ##
----------
(30)25802112
32(89)02212
(32)2330
```

need output like

```
## output ##
----------
25802112
3202212
2330
```

is there any simple update something like that can work in my case
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Sorry guys  didn't know you are this quick in solving , I am slow in editing my post  wit appropriate info.

Comment: Oops, You have changed the original data set you gave. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Whirl Mind  I am sorry  was editing my post and about to write the query same query as my present query . but  got answers before that . really appreciate all the help

Comment: No probs, @andhra. I revised my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select case when charindex('(',col1) > 0 and charindex(')',col1) > 0 
            then substring(col1, 1, charindex('(',col1) -1) +
                 substring(col1, charindex(')', col1) + 1, len(col1))
            else col1 end as col1
from TableName
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the CharIndex of the character ) .
2. Add 1 to it.
3. Use the Substring function to get that part of the string, starting from result of Step 2 and asking for Len(string).

Note : If all column values are unlikely to contain the right brace, then you may have to use a Case Statement to handle those that do and those that don't.

```
SubString(Col1, CharIndex(')', Col1) + 1, Len(Col1))
```

EDIT : In response to OP's changing of sample values, which included the occurrence of non-paranthesed-value in the beginning : here is the edited code, that provides the answer for the revised sample data set.

```
Case When CharIndex('(', Col1) > 1 Then 
        Left ( Col1, CharIndex('(', Col1) - 1 ) +
            SubString(Col1, CharIndex(')', Col1) + 1, Len(Col1))

    Else 
        SubString(Col1, CharIndex(')', Col1) + 1, Len(Col1))
    End
```

Comment: Thank you man for quick answer and all the interest that you have showed .

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps..

```
create table repl
(
    i varchar(20)
)

insert into repl values('(30)25802112')
insert into repl values('(32)2330')
insert into repl values('(89)02212')

select CAST(SUBSTRING(i,PATINDEX('%)%',i)+1, len(i)) AS bigint)
from repl
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Rtrim(Substring(numbersWithBrackets, charindex(')', numbersWithBrackets) + 1, len(numbersWithBrackets)))
FROM t
```